# Method should check array against itself?

Tags: java, arrays, slick2d

I tried to make a method to tell me if my array contained any duplicate coordinates, and if so set a boolean to true, else, set it to false. Any idea why it continuously returns false?

```
    public void check(){
    if(point[particle].equals(point) == true){
        check = true;
    } else {
        check = false;
    }
}
```

point = Point array

particle = Current particle

check = My boolean used to check

Answer (score 2):

Look at this part of the code (from the condition of your `if`-statement):

```
point[particle].equals(point)
```

I think there is some [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) (or something of that sort) going on here. `point` seems to be an array but you are testing for equality between a member of this array and the array itself -- this is why you keep getting `false`. Check your variable names and see if you accidentally used the same name for two different variables.

---

As a note,

```
if (condition == true) {
    check = true;
} else {
    check = false;
}
```

can be simplified to

```
check = condition;
```